# Function returns true but if statement says otherwise

Tags: php, function, class, if-statement

I need someone with fresh eyes. I have a function that is checking to see if they have access to that topic, or section in my discussion board. This is the problem. I don't know if i'm typing something incorrectly.

The function is returning 
bool(true) and Granted (For Debugging)

My if statement is echoing out that I don't have permission.

```
public function hasPermission($key) {
    $group = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE `id` = ?", array($key));
    if ($group->count()){
        if ($key === 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);
            switch ($key) {
                case 2:
                    $string = 'member';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $string = 'admin';
                    break;
            }
            print_r($string);
            if ($permissions[$string] === 1) {
                if ($this->_user->hasPermission($string)){
                    print('Granted');
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the the part that I don't understand. I know that you can call a function inside and if statement and it will continue if the function is true.

```
if (true) {
   //do this
} else {
   //do this
}
```

Right?

Well my function is returning true but my if statement is not executing the correct block of code.

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $forum->topics($id);
    $topics = $forum->results();

    $permission = $forum->first();
    if (!empty($topics)) {
        foreach ($topics as $topic) {
            $list .= '<tr>';
            $list .= '<td><a href="topic.php?id=' . $topic->id . '">' . $topic->thread_title .'</a></td>';
            $list .= '<td>Mr_Nasty_Time405</td>';
            $list .= '<td>25</td>';
            $list .= '<td>400</td>';
            $list .= '</tr>';
        }
    } else {
        $list .= '<tr>';
        $list .= '<td>There are no Sections under this category would you like to create one?';
        $list .= '</tr>';
    }
    if($forum->hasPermission($permission->permissions)) {
    $error = "Granted";
    } else {$error = "You don't have permission";}
} else {Redirect::to('404');}?>
```

Comment: So when you `print_r($forum->hasPermission($permission->permissions))` where that line is, what do you get? The wording of `$permission->permissions` is a little weird considering your `hasPermission` function seems to accept a singular `$key` - are you sure you're sending the correct parameters? I'm being lead to think you're sending an array to a function that expects a single integer value.

Comment: $permission->permissions is pulling from the database either a number 1 2 3. These number are associated with my groups id. So the $permission->permissions is returning just 1 value

Comment: Cool, and what about my first question?

Comment: Thats in the HTML part of the file, If I print_r($forum->hasPermission($permission->permissions)) I would get 1 and if I var_dump($forum->hasPermission($permission->permissions)) I get bool(true).